# Difference between Adjoint of a matrix and its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transpose

For simplicity let $T:R^{n}\rightarrow R^{n},$ be a linear operator and $[A]_T$ be the matrix of  operator $T.$ Then matrix of adjoint $T^{\times}$ operator of $T$ is given as 
$$[A]_{T^{\times}}=[A]_{T}^t$$ where $t$ denotes transpose of a matrix.

My Question is that then from above equality the notions of transpose of a matrix and adjoint of a matrix are same, they why we use separate names?? while in some textbooks adjoint of a matrix is referred to the transpose of coefficient matrix.

Comment: I should think that this definition requires a self-dual basis.

Answer (score 6):

In the context of *complex* vector spaces, they are different: the adjoint matrix is the *conjugate* of the transpose matrix.

Comment: To complement this answer, adjoints are defined in inner product spaces, while transpose is a more general concept.

Answer (score 4):

First, the adjoint is defined as a *conjugate transpose* for complex operators, but this reduces to a pure transpose in the real case.

Also, the transpose is only defined for *finite* matrices (finite-dimensional operators). The adjoint operator can be defined for *infinite-dimensional* operators and even more general things, like Hilbert spaces. Hence it makes sense to call it by a different name.

Comment: The transpose makes sense for general operators of normed linear spaces, so I think this is misleading. The tranpose of $T:V\to W$ is the map $W^\ast\to V^\ast$ taking $\psi\mapsto\psi\circ T$. Under this definition, viewing a matrix $A$ (with some given basis $B$) as an operator $T$, the matrix representation of $T$-transpose (under the canonical basis $B^\ast$) is exactly $A^t$, in the setting of maps $\Bbb K^n\to\Bbb K^m$